# Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 48318382080 bytes

Tags: php, apache, nginx, битрикс

При запуске php-cкриптов Битрикс через кроны на сервере периодически возникает ошибка

```
Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 48318382080 bytes: mmap: 
No space left on device (28)
```

После перезагрузки `apache` скрипты запускаются, но через некоторое время ошибка повторяется.Пробовал увеличивать размер выделяемой памяти через параметр `memory_limit` до 70 Gb. Ошибка также возникает.

Результат команды `ipcs -lm`

```
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 32768
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

Результат команды `df -h`

```
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  188G   86G   93G  49% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   6.3G  224K  6.3G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                    19G     0   19G   0% /run/shm
/dev/md1                                                496M   33M  438M   7% /boot
```

На сервере установлен `nginx + apache`. Nginx используется в качестве proxy-сервера. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: То есть ты думаешь, что если написать в пхп скрипте memory_limit = 70 Gb, то на сервере сразу столько памяти прибавится? Типа, прибежит инженер техподдержки, и воткнет нужное количество плат памяти?

Comment: На сервере установлено 64 Gb оперативной памяти. Если я правильно понимаю, memory_limit ограничивает количество памяти, выделяемое для скриптов.

Comment: `No space left on device` намекает на то, что закончилось место на жестком диске, насколько могу судить.

Comment: Такой вариант тоже был. Но свободное место на жестком диске есть. Добавил в описание ошибки результат команды `df -h`.

Answer (score 3):

Настройка PHP `memory_limit` не имеет никакого отношения к shared memory. Архитектурно PHP - shared nothing. shared memory - что-то отдельное.

Такой fatal error генерирует расширение OPcache и смотрит на настройку `opcache.memory_consumption`.
Попытка отожрать 45 гигов памяти при всего 64 на железке... Вряд ли это хорошая мысль. Если это не банальная ошибка настройки `opcache.memory_consumption` (например, думали, что размер в килобайтах - а на самом деле эта настройка указывается в мегабайтах), то нужно разбираться с кодом, что в shared memory пишется и зачем так много. Детальнее подсказать, к сожалению, не смогу, от битрикса держусь так далеко, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Значение параметра memory_consumption.
`opcache.memory_consumption=46080`

Comment: То есть как раз 45 гигабайт.